# Find the value of $S=\frac{5}{1^2.4^2}+\frac{11}{4^2.7^2}+\frac{17}{7^2.10^2}+.....\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series

After a lot of observation, I was able to find one pattern. If $S$ is multiplied by 3

$$3S=\frac{3\cdot 5}{1^2\cdot 4^2}+\frac{3\cdot 11}{4^2\cdot 7^2}......\infty$$
$$3S=\frac{(4-1)(4+1)}{1^2\cdot 4^2}+\frac{(7-4)(7+4)}{4^2\cdot 7^2}....\infty$$

I am pretty sure this is the right way to solve, but I don’t know what to do with this further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Telescoping sum 
\begin{eqnarray*}
3S= \frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{4^2} +\frac{1}{4^2} -\frac{1}{7^2} +\frac{1}{7^2} -\frac{1}{10^2} +\cdots.
\end{eqnarray*}

Edit: each term is ... 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{ 3(6n+5)}{(3n+1)^2(3n+4)^2}= \frac{(3n+4)^2-(3n+1)^2}{(3n+1)^2(3n+4)^2}=\frac{1}{(3n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(3n+4)^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was telescoping too. But I didn’t understand how, and I still don’t. Can you please write what you did to arrive at this?

Answer (score 0):

$$ S=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac {6n-1}{\left (3n-2\right)^{2}\left (3n+1\right)^{2}}}=\frac {1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\left (\frac {1}{\left (3\left (n-1\right)+1\right)^{2}}-\frac {1}{\left (3n+1\right)^{2}}\right )}=\frac {1}{3} $$